# Do we want to participate in Winter Bash 2013?

Tags: discusión, winter-bash

Those of you who were here this time last year may remember [Winter Bash 2012](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash).  **Spanish Language & Usage** did not participate, but many other Stack Exchange sites did.

It's coming up again, 16 December 2013 through 3 January 2014, and you, the community, get to decide whether we participate. A decision must be made prior to 1 December.

For those of us young 'uns who weren't around last year, Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can "wear":

[image]

Sites vote explicitly to participate, and if the idea is welcomed by site's users, it will be enabled in the aforementioned period. It's important to know that even if Winter Bash is enabled, users can explicitly opt out if they want to (there will be "I hate hats" option on their profile page which will revert the site to its familiar look for the user).

Please vote on one of the answers below to indicate your opinion on the matter.

Comment: Que es Winter Bash?

Comment: Winter Bash is a "game" of sorts, where "hats" are awarded for certain achievements. Follow the link above in the question for info and some examples from last year's event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I ❤ Hats

Please, please, please, let **Spanish Language & Usage** participate! I'll cry if we don't!

Answer (score 1):

### Hats are dumb

So are fun games, and silliness. **Bahhh-Humbug!**